# Rails 3: select helper method default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have this select helper call:

```
<%= f.select :macro_process_id, MacroProcess.all.collect { |mp| [mp.name, mp.id]} %>
```

How can i change this that if `:macro_process_id` has a value, then the selected element should be equal to that value?

If that makes any sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= f.select :macro_process_id, MacroProcess.all.collect { |mp| [mp.name, mp.id]}, MacroProcess.find(:macro_process_id) %>
```

The addition that I have made, will make it the default value selected among the other values.

For more info, look here: [form-select-helper-in-ruby-on-rails](http://ashleyangell.com/2009/11/form-select-helper-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: hi @jatin that gives an error ``Couldn't find MacroProcess with ID=macro_process_id``

Comment: @Mo: what is the value of `:macro_process_id`?

Comment: its an integer, its the macro_process ID so it can establish a relationship

Comment: then why is it, that it is showing this error `Couldn't find MacroProcess with ID=macro_process_id`. Try this: Remove the .all.collect block, pass static data, with 1 value that would be Macroprocess ID, and see if it works